# Copy Memory Only Using Store And Subtraction

Tags: atomic-code-golf, assembly

A peer of mine approached me with this challenge and I wasn't able to come up with an elegant solution. After discussing my approach, we began to wonder what the people at Code Golf would come up with.

## Given

- A processor that implements only two instructions:

  1. STO <register>, <address> (`store` from this `register` to this `address`)
  2. SUB <register>, <address> (`subtract` the value at this `address` from this  `register`)
- It also only contains `2`, `32-bit` registers: `A` and `B`
- As well as `2`, `32-bit` RAM address: `0x00` and `0x01`
- The values of `A` and `B` are unknown

## Challenge

Write a program to `copy` RAM address `0x00` into `0x01` optimised to use the `fewest` number of instructions possible.

Comment: Welcome to PCG! Note that this isn't a very good challenge. It's simple enough to likely only have one good solution. Try using the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first next time to get feedback about proposed challenges. Thanks.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thank you, I'm new and figured there was a better way to do this. I'm sorry for the poor question and I greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming registers are signed and/or wrapping

8 instructions:

```
STO A 0x01
SUB A 0x01
SUB A 0x00
STO A 0x00
SUB A 0x00
SUB A 0x00
STO A 0x00
STO A 0x01
```

A 7-instruction version provided by lrn:

```
STO A 0x01
SUB A 0x01
SUB A 0x00
STO A 0x01
SUB A 0x01
SUB A 0x01
STO A 0x01
```

Comment: That and the next instruction serve to zero register A. Then we do a what amounts to [00]=-[00], then some more stuff to restore [00] to its original value while simultaneously setting A to that value, then we write that value to [01]. The requirement was that [01] and [00] both end up having the value that [00] initially had.

Comment: Oops, I read the challenge as being to swap the memory locations.

Comment: @feersum: I don't think you could do that with this command set without adding a third address.

Comment: All without using register `B`. Nice! This is probably the optimal solution.

Comment: A 3rd address or maybe an XOR instruction. I don't see a way for there to be an answer any simpler than this. It was definitely better than mine, so I marked it as the answer. Congratulations!

Comment: @Brett Can you post yours, please? I'm interested.

Comment: Why store A to 0x00 in the second to last step? If you use 0x01 as temporary in step 4 and forward, you don't need to store back into 0x00. That is: `STO A 0x01; SUB A 0x01; SUB A 0x00; STO A 0x01; SUB A 0x01; SUB A 0x01; STO A 0x01` should copy 0x00 to 0x01 and keep 0x00 unchanged in one instruction less.